# Magento translations in external script

Tags: magento, translation, magento-1.5

I want to be able to use `$this->__('String to translate')` in an external script. How do I do this? Magento version `1.5.1.0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
require 'app/Mage.php'; // here you should use the correct path to Mage.php file

Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton('core/translate')->init('sv_SE', true); // UPDATE
$to_translate = "String to translate";
$translated = Mage::helper('core')->__($to_translate);
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to be working (no errors) but it doesn't translate if I put a translation in the `translate.csv` file. How do I tell it which language to use? I want it to use `sv_SE`.

Comment: I have added a new line of code to force the Magento translator work in sv_SE language. Not sure if it works, but the best way to accomplish your task would be to create different store views for each language: http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/magento-design-terminologies4

Comment: The init function expects an area as a parameter, not a locale. Please see the correct answer below: Mage::getSingleton('core/translate')->setLocale('sv_SE')->init('frontend', true);

Comment: How can we done this activity in magento2

Answer (score 10):

I think the right way to set locale is:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/translate')->setLocale('sv_SE')->init('frontend', true);
```

Comment: If you copy and paste this code, this will retrieve the transactions without using the cache, the right way is: `Mage::getSingleton('core/translate')->setLocale('sv_SE')->init('frontend');` You're warned!